# How can I implement sorting with Active Model Serializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, active-model-serializers

What I would like to do is pass a list of columns to sort by as a sport parameter and have AMS sort the response based on those parameters.  For Example if I use this `url _GET /authors?sort=lastname,firstname_` it would sport by lastname then firstname. However if I did this `GET /authors?sort=number_of_books,lastname,firstnam*` it would return authors based on the number of books, then lastname and firstname.

It appears AMS does not do this by default (and they are not going to do it in the future), but can I do something in the serializer that will do this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience AMS doesn't really concern itself with sorting. This seems like something you'd do before serializing. Perhaps in the controller or better yet in the model.

UPDATE

@CalebSayre if your sort parameter is just a simple list of fields to sort by you could probably get away with something as simple as this.

```
render json: Author.order(params[:sort]), serializer: AuthorSerializer
```

If no sort params are passed in it'll just skip the order clause.

Comment: I agree with Dan. What you're really wanting is to create a Search or Filter object that accepts those parameters, does all the sorting logic, then returns the collection. Then pass this collection and the meta data to AMS.

Comment: @TylerFerraro I guess that is really what my question is... How can I pass in fields as a sort parameter so that I can do the sorting?